# The meaning of „lauten“ as in, „Wie lautet die Vergangenheitsform für dieses Verb?“

Tags: meaning-in-context

Based on LEO, it seems that this would translate to, “How does the past tense of this verb *read*.” Is that right? Would it be incorrect to simply say, „Was ist die Vergangenheitsform für dieses Verb?“ Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a good way to put it.
Essentially it is the "reading", the literal string of letters or numbers, that something **is**. Because of that, it is somtimes compared to *sein* (to be).
Your name *is* a string of letters, your telephone number is just numbers, but also, if something is a longer quote, like a verdict, you can use it as well.

> Die Telefonnummer lautet 21103. (The telephone number is 21103)
> Mein Name lautet Mark. (My name is Mark)
> Das Urteil lautete "lebenslänglich".  (The verdict is "life sentence")
> Die Regel lautete: "Wer anderen eine Grube gräbt, fällt selbst hinein".   (The rule is: "[Idiom]".)

Comment: Very useful. Thank you!